# How do I make a rock with magical properties teleport people?

Tags: technology, science-in-society, materials

Thinking about it, you probably need more context than that, so here we go.

Basically, in my Earth/Alt Universe world, there's this new magical rock, let's call it, *stranglium*! Stranglium, on touch with living matter (think plants, people, *living* things), becomes gold (the object in question, not the rock). As well, adding Stranglium to anything makes said thing 300% more efficient and better at its job. Coating a gun in Stranglium makes the gun 300% more accurate, powerful/faster, etc.

With that, alloying Stranglium with other things so classified that *I* don't even know it, creates a translucent, crystal-like object that heals, (cue cliché healing rock).

Among with other things (that I totally haven't thought of yet), I want this rock to be one of the main reasons why teleporters exist in my 1890-1970 world. Specifically during the Cold War.

Onto the teleporter, I'm looking for a few things

1. I don't want to use the same excuse of "Alloying it with *x*,*y*, and *z* creates a material that teleports people", or applying it to the rock itself.

2.The teleporter in question should be small, it should be like the size of a large mat (x and z, not y) or something slightly bigger.

3.If possible, I want the machine **NOT** to use Stranglium

The list is in order of what I don't want to see/hear/etc. (1 is something that I *really* don't want to see, while 3 is that I expect to be broken right away). Or hell, is a teleporter even possible using this metal?

Now looking over it, this is probably really vague/not what I should be asking, but I'm really darn stuck on how to move on.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Worldbuilding Yeti. Since this is a material that you have created, the way it teleports people is also up to you. There isn't much we can do to help because there are so many conflicting properties in your material. If anything touches stranglium becomes gold, then how do you process it? Everything it touches becomes gold and gold is a pretty soft malleable metal. Next coating a gun can't make it more powerful... there is only so much gun power in the bullet... and if you held a stranglium coated gun, why haven't you, the gun or bullet turned to gold?

Comment: Going along with your question, I could suggest something like, liquid or gas Stranglium acts as a time travel machine, so once you melt it and get it hot enough, you can jump in and get time traveled back into the past.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!  We're glad you could join us!  When you have a moment, please [click here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388) to learn more about our culture and take our [tour].  Not to make a big deal out of it, but you've asked us how a rock (paragraph #2 and your title) teleports people without using the rock itself (issue #3).  Is that what you really meant?  You may want to use our [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168).

Comment: I know thinking up names for magic rocks isn't easy. "Stranglium" looks the word would sound like "strangle-um" as in strangling someone. You want a name more like "strangeum" pronounced "strange-ee-um". Perhaps?

Comment: A nitpick, if you don't mind, or perhaps a clue. If adding stranglium to anything makes it 300% better, how do you make an alloy?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to make stranglium a cause of the teleporter existing, is just to use the healing rock to save some person who later invents the teleporter, which technically counts.

Another way which is probably more appropriate to what you want to ask is that the teleporter prototypes tend to mangle the thing that they send, and the existence of the healing rock thing allows them to heal the people who were teleported, meaning it becomes an actually useable transportation thing instead of a killing machine, until perhaps further advances make it not require the healing when it becomes more accurate

A third answer is to make the way the healing rock works more convenient to this idea. you could say that exposure to the healing rock makes the persons form more stable (regardless of whether it was actually used for healing), making the teleportation reliable.

It might also be worth noting that the existence of unexplainable supernatural things is going to make scientists more likely to investigate ridiculous impossible things.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well you seem to be asking what is 'possible'. Stranglium is already not possible as you have described it, it is magical. Is 'possible' really something that matters once magic is involved? If you are looking for internal consistency in a magic system, which is entirely reasonable, it is up to you to define what is possible and what is not.

As to a teleporter, perhaps the teleporter is actually a container that houses an interdimensional spirit of exceeding intellect, capable of comprehending the very fabric of reality itself? The teleporter functions by simply prompting the consciousness within it to imagine you in a different location, and when that being concentrates really hard on that request it alters reality in such a way that you ARE at the desired location?

A link between the beings and the rock could be whatever you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

**Nanites!**

https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Nanomachines

> Nanotechnology has become an all-purpose magic substitute for soft
>   science fiction and sci-fi-flavored fantasy. Nano is the latest Sci Fi
>   Name Buzzword; it is the new pseudo-Greek for phlebotinum. Nanotech
>   supplies a myriad of exciting powers with a satisfying patina of
>   plausibility. ... Once you have a vast mass of these robots, all ready
>   to accept orders and shuffle stuff around at the molecular level, they
>   can potentially do anything nature does and much, much more... More
>   often fiction delights in taking nanotech way, way beyond the
>   plausible. Nanomachines, "nanites" or "nanobots" are a writer's best
>   friend. Writers are not expected to show the nanomachines doing
>   whatever it is that they do, all they have to do are the results. And
>   the results can be anything. Nanomachines can be depicted as masses of
>   cloud/liquid in external "colonies", Voluntary Shapeshifting Blobs, or
>   syringes of stuff to be injected into humans and have fantastic
>   results, usually in the form of superpowers, but sometimes in the form
>   of a Baleful Polymorph or Harmful Healing.

My thoughts on the unifying property of your Stranglium nannies: they build, really really fast.  This explains the better gun: it is not the same gun, but a new one they built, minus imperfections.  This explains the healing properties: it is not the same body, but a new one they have built, minus the wounds.  This explains the teleporting.  It is not you that teleports; you are nearly instantaneously broken down into atoms, but a new body is built for you at the destination.

The gold piece is an artifact of the test mode built in for factory checking of the stranglium bots.  Again, the thing is not turned into gold.  A new thing is built, which is made of gold.  The old thing is recycled.

The users of stranglium are not the inventors or creators of stranglium.  They found it.  Its long lost Makers would be horrified to see the uses their nanites are being put to.  Current users may be unaware of the mechanism of action Stranglium uses.